# mPDF outputs the pdf as symbols insted of characters

Tags: character, symbols, mpdf

I want to display the pdf in browser. I use `mpdf` to generate pdf and it generates correctly. When I use

```
$mpdf->Output('binders/' . $filename . '.pdf', 'I');
```

it outputs as the following symbols.
When I use `F` instead of `I`, i'm getting the pdf saved on the folder with correct characters.

Can someone help me please.

%PDF-1.4 %���� 3 0 obj <> /Contents 4 0 R>> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x��[�o��*���j#���d���ٙ��)dYvlĎ�]��ئ-��^�(EpE�,Ăd!J�� �,5��O������۽;^h�ݛ�����y�͜���S��.wN}�&�}��R2�"�vU\;��_��~|���_)q�V���ִ�m]E�-��ŚX�@�mh6:���R�]�tq������@�wk9w��C�)D؞.���@�Su<��K[�)<&�-]lYL�J�]*]E<�:|���z��.�e٤9hH@�b&� �]��f�5s���uE�?7]Z9���5k��`6�j�j�!��Zѧ�*�j���L���Zƪ=�EH�vp�����O�0���g|� �����F��� ���e�R�br�]�H"k⁽�^�@v����}�[{І#���,�8A;�X����u8��E���D�o�3�YqQd�Ls:p�)�����ϸ��U��s���n�3_�ç��G�/�����J��Q|����;]�$���/�+R��j��V�]�X��k��Jj��v�]X��d*������su�L�je"3����k��=�����F��;Q���H����\���D�$�4�V���;��ƈ���{nJ��36���NיFl��nt�U���Kݜ>��[Lv�L;�

Comment: "it outputs as .." -- where? Per [documentation](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=125), `I` should "send the file inline to the browser".

Comment: @jongware yes in the browser

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I am at the same thing with mpdf

Comment: Which browser are you using? Is it capable to display pdf files inline? Aren't you overriding the content-type header someplace after calling the `Output` method?

Answer (score 0):

The string is a binary PDF representation and its presence means `Content-type: application/pdf` header is not sent correctly or it is
overriden by your code or setup. Most likely by `text/plain` or `text/html`.

Try to figure out these:

- Are you resetting `Content-type` header in PHP code somewhere after calling the mPDF `Output` method?
- Is your server forcing a different `Content-type` somewhere in your setup?
- Does your browser support displaying `application/pdf` Content-type directly?
- Does the `D` Output mode offer the file for downloading or does it display the same characters?

If the `D` mode displays the same characters, then the `Content-type` header is most likely being overriden somewhere in your app or setup after calling the mPDF `Output` method.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `exit();` to the end of your code. Hope it helps.